# подключение к серверу

Tags: node.js

У меня такой вопрос. На компьютере я запускаю сервер Node. Могу ли я через браузер смартфона подключится к нему по локальной сети (через маршрутизатор)? И если да то как?

Comment: Точно так же, как и к любому другому - указываете адрес в адресной строке и подключаетесь...

Comment: Не получается. На самом компьютере сервер отвечает а на смартфоне не хочет. А какой адрес надо вводить в браузер 127.0.0.   или 192.168. ?

Comment: Адрес сервера в локальной сети. И не забыть убедиться, что для сервера разрешены подключения в брандмауре.

Comment: Что такое адрес сервера в сети?

Comment: Вбейте в поисковике что то вроде "Как организованы локальные сети" - думаю, после прочтения 2-х 3х статей вопрос исчезнет сам собой.

Comment: Ну допустим у меня сейчас адрес 192.168.42.167 и порт 3000, браузер в компьютере отвечает на 192.168.42.167:3000 а смартфон не может. Что тут не так?